# Android L cards using CardView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

I am having a play with the new Android L SDK and I can't figure out how to implement CardView. Seems like I'm missing something - any advice is very much appreciated!

So far I have the following declared as part of my activity:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/waitingHeader"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notificationText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="hello"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notificationTex"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="hello2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Naively I was hoping that would give me two cards with **hello** and **hello2** however all I see is a single card with **hello** - the second card is missing. How can I create multiple cards using CardView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of cardview as ViewGroup Like linear layout or Relative layout. If you want two cardview then use two cardview and keep root layout as Linear or Relative Layout.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/waitingHeader"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

     <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notificationText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="hello"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/waitingHeader"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notificationTex"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="hello2"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Ah there's the missing link! I assumed that CardView can do more than just wrap the view in the card. So I guess if I want to create cards dynamically I need to wrap them in RecyclerView. Thanks!

Comment: @Manoj please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393540/no-shadow-elevation-underneath-second-card-if-there-are-two-card-in-the-layout